# VBA range.find error 91

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, runtime

The below code is attempting to scroll through a range of columns and format the max value in each of the columns.

Previously it had worked up to a certain point.  Most likely failing because it was searching for a value within a formula.

However, now it will not even succeed on the first column.

I have verified that the range object is set, the max value must be found, and I also attempted just to search for a specific number I know is in that range.

The same error occurs in any case.  I believe the error is between
 `rw = rng.Find(max).row`
and the `with` block.

Code is pasted below and any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Sub testMaxRetail()

Dim max As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Integer
Dim cell As Variant
Dim colCnt As Integer
Dim i As Integer

colCnt = 12

For i = 2 To colCnt

    Set rng = Sheets("Annual").Range(Cells(1, i).Address, Cells(6000, i).Address)

    'clearing old formatting
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And cell.Font.Bold = True Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            cell.Font.Bold = False
        End If
    Next cell

    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Sheets("Annual").Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(6000, i)))

    rw = rng.Find(max).Row


    With Sheets("Annual").Cells(rw, i)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Conditional formatting?

Comment: Unfortunately, another part of the program involves inserting rows into the sheet so conditional formatting doesn't really work as it splits up the formatted range every time I insert.

Comment: Your code work's fine for me, only when the cells are values not formulas..

Comment: [Object variable not set (Error 91)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/object-variable-not-set-error-91)

Comment: Problem was a mismatch in    max    variable and the values displayed on screen.    The solution was to format the   max   variable in the Find() method to ensure that they match

Comment: Should you be using `.address` to set the rng?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't iterate through cells one at a time to check formatting and clear in need. Just clear the whole block in one go, regardless whether the individual cells have formatting or not. Also, note that if you have two values that equal max, your existing code will only highlight one of them. Is this going to pose a problem?

Comment: Clearing formatting was not an option as I needed to preserve certain formatting, headers, summary rows, etc.    I removed the .address portion, forgot that was on there as I was trying anything to make this work.  I realized that the first matching value it found would be highlighted.  For my purposes, that is fine

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
rw = rng.Find(max).Row
```

for this:

```
rw = rng.Find(What:=max, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

In order to find formula value.

The `with` statement is not causing the error.